# Super simple question about solidify of two planes that form a corner

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So, I have two planes

1. moving them to form a corner
2. joining them into one object(with ctrl + j)
   [image]

3)now applying solidify modifer on them, to make this object thicker, but it applys only to one side(one previous plane) and I need to apply it to both at same time, what am I doing wrong?
[image]
ps don't look at vertex group, it's empty
pps ticking Even Thickness seems helping, but other plane start to get thicker only after first is x 1000000000 times thicker

Comment: I suspect that you need to apply scale.  Select object in object mode, ctrl-a -> scale.

Comment: @Nathan wowo, can You plz post it as answer? So can confirm it as right one, it helped, thx you bro , you are my hero of the day!!! Best wishes)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not posting as an answer, because this is stuff that is basically duplicated a thousand-fold all over the site.  I don't care about the points-- I want you to get the result you want, and I want BSE to have focused questions and answers without a bunch of duplicates, so that's why I'm answering in comments here.  But if you want to post as answer and mark it solved, go for it!

Comment: Also, last time I posted that as an answer, it got deleted because it was so short that it triggered user review, and then it gets deleted, and then I get irritated.  I don't want to get irritated, so I say stuff in comments instead sometimes.

Comment: @Nathan got it, no it's Your knowledge and experience, I don't have right for this, sorry for duplicate, couldn't find it with google for some reasone, yeah, now can go and print this for my fresh tesseract, thank you again, sir!

Comment: "couldn't find it with google for some reason" I know, I wasn't saying it's your fault or anything.  When you're starting out, it's like, how do you know what to search for when you don't know what the problem is?  If I could figure out a good question, that beginners could find, for which the answer was, "Apply scale," then I'd make that question myself.  But I can't figure out what question that would be.  People that needed to know would never find it.